# Automatically respond "Yes" to R library prompt

Tags: r, bash, docker, automation

I'm working to define a Docker container which can be spun up in a cloud environment and run some reporting on our firm's database and spin itself down, with as little involvement from our data science team (including myself) as possible.

I'm pretty much done getting everything up and running, with one irritating exception- the reporting is done in R using some code that we've been using for a few years. I'm building on top of Rocker verse, and I'm adding the needs library.

The annoying thing (in this use case) about needs is that when it is first run, it asks the following:

```
>library('needs')

Should `needs` load itself when it's... needed?   (this is recommended)

1: No
2: Yes

Selection:
```

In a typical interactive setting this is fine, I just type "Yes" and hit enter and I'm good to go. However, when I want the whole environment to build and run once a week on its own, I don't want to have to answer this question. I'd like it to assume Yes.

What I've tried so far includes each of these:

```
library('needs', quiet=TRUE)
library('needs', quietly=TRUE)
suppressMessages(library('needs', quietly=TRUE))
suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(library('needs', quietly = T)))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library('needs', quietly=TRUE))
```

none of which solves the issue. The [needs documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/needs/needs.pdf) provides for *changing* this setting later in a programmatic way, but not for *defining* the setting when first running needs:

> Recommended use is to allow the function to autoload when prompted the
>   first time the package is loaded interactively. To change this setting
>   later, run needs:::autoload(TRUE) or needs:::autoload(FALSE) to turn
>   autoloading on or off, respectively.

I've also tried quietly installing needs, also to no avail. Unfortunately, I can't run bash commands in my Dockerfile to respond Yes, or at least I haven't found a way.

I'd like to avoid removing dependencies for needs, as it will involve a LOT of code refactoring.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you! :]
-Vince

**Update**

Solution is a bit hacky, but in my Dockerfile I'm doing a vim edit of the file which needs assigns to the sysfile variable:

```
sysfile <- system.file("extdata", "promptUser", package = "needs")
```

which for ME was /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/needs/extdata/promptUser, and changing its contents from "1" to "0" solving my problem.

Comment: In bash, did you try something like *command* `<<< 'Yes'` ?

Comment: Hi cdarke, thanks for your help here. I have tried that, and unfortunately it doesn't work, as it's effectively initiating a new bash command instead of running this as an R command in the R shell. If I try to add something like R -e "Yes" it simply initiates a new R shell and fails since Yes alone is not a valid R command. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution would probably be to make it so it doesn't ask the question in the first place.  You can view the code it runs on package load on github: https://github.com/cran/needs/blob/master/R/needs-package.R

If you set the option it checks for before hand then it doesn't need to ask the question in the first place:

```
options(needs.promptUser = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, Dason! I did in fact try this, and got this error:


> options("needs.promptUser") = FALSE


Error in options("needs.promptUser") = FALSE :  target of assignment expands to non-language object

If I run > options("needs.promptUser"), then I get this output: 
$needs.promptUser
NULL

Comment: Actually, I now see that I was setting the option incorrectly! It ran successfully in the form which you shared, and yet needs still prompts me with the question. :/ It appears that needs is setting the value of that option explicitly immediately before checking it.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't notice that part before. Perhaps you could run the portion that overwrites the sysfile before loading needs.  (On mobile so I can't test)

Comment: Thanks Dason, I'll give it a shot when I'm back in the office tomorrow and report back. :]

Comment: Hi Dason, I was able to open the file which needs assigns to the "sysfile" variable (in sysfile <- system.file("extdata", "promptUser", package = "needs")), and it's simply the number 1. I did a vim edit to change it to 0 and this FINALLY achieves what I was hoping for! I'm honestly surprised that there isn't another, more general approach to accomplishing this, though I can recognize that it's likely a fairly narrow use case. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @vincep I'd suggest submitting an issue and describing your use case. The author may be receptive to modifying the onload procedure to circumvent having to go through the dialog. https://github.com/joshkatz/needs/issues

Comment: @vincep Best of luck.  After posting that I investigated and although the author has made a few contributions on github this year there haven't been any changes to that particular package or responses to issues in the recent past.